# Windows Phone- Internal Wrapped Exceptions

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, windows-phone, bing-maps

My app is throwing MS.Internal.WrappedExceptions on launch.  I'm not sure the source of the exceptions, and I'm very new to coding, so any pointers will be appreciated.  It goes directly to the exception while its displaying the loading screen.

Heres my XAML:  If you need the code behind, let me know

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"  
    x:Class="WPMapExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Where'd I Park?" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontSize="68"/>
            <Button x:Name="findme" Content="Find Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Width="197" Click="startLocationButton_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="savecar" Content="Save Car" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Width="197" Click="saveloadButton_Click" Margin="247,-80,0,0"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="61" Margin="176,-70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Source="/Images/feature.settings.png"/>
            <Button Content="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="61" Margin="199,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" RenderTransformOrigin="0.529,0.507" Opacity="0" Click="settings_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,185,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <my:Map Mode="AerialWithLabels" ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomLevel="12" CredentialsProvider="***removed***" x:Name="map" Margin="0,0,0,120" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="notebox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="65" Margin="6,363,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Notes:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440" FontSize="20"/>

        </Grid>
        <ProgressBar Foreground="Blue" x:Name="ProgBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,196" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="480" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And the debug output:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B87A23B5-2904-4341-9369-A80CA7F63BA0}\Install\WPMapExample.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B87A23B5-2904-4341-9369-A80CA7F63BA0}\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Device.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\LocationService.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Device.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The program '[2236] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your `<my:Map` control. I haven't worked with it but I'm sure if you comment it - everything will work fine.

Comment: Do you know what it is thats wrong? If I cant try commenting it out, because I have alot of stuff in the code behind pointing to it.

Comment: If you have lots of code behind, it is much more difficult to tell what's wrong. Try to look at the `InnerException` property when the exception is thrown, maybe it can clarify exactly what error is.

Comment: It's saying "UIElement.Arrange(finalRect) cannot be called with Infinite or NaN values in finalRect. ".  What does that mean?

Comment: I tried to google your error message and there are some people who have the same problem. I was right, it concerns the Map control, more specifically the Pushpin class: http://blog.slimcode.com/2011/03/28/late-binding-bing-maps-and-pushpins-with-an-unknown-position/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that article